# Loading assembly from a file and calling GetExportedTypes

Tags: types, reflection, .net-assembly

I had an application under .Net framework 4.5 that would open an assembly from a file and return the tyes in it as an array which I could then work with.

I need to update that application to .Net 5 and when I call GetTypes or GetExportedTypes on it it throws a FileNotFoundException.  I know that the reason is that there is an embedded dependancy within that dll but I don't mind ignoring any types that would be contained in that.  I just need the types in the base dll.  Anyway I can't seem to find any way to retrieve the types without hitting this exception and scoured google for the new proper way to do this but to no avail.

Here's a simplified block of code that used to work in .Net framework.

```
    private bool CheckAssembly(FileInfo assemblyPath)
    {
        var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath.FullName);

        var types = asm.GetExportedTypes();

        ...
    }
```

Comment: So is it impossible to get the list of types in any way as long as the dependency is not loaded?  As I mentioned I don't need the types from the dependency.

Comment: Essentially I just need a list of types in a dll that I have.  How can I accomplish this?  Can it be done using the method I have posted but with some modifications?  Or do I need to use an entirely different approach?

Comment: Any help out there on this?

Comment: I just found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/inspect-contents-using-metadataloadcontext which appears to be exactly what I need but it doesn't work with .Net 5 assemblies.  Is there anything similar under .net 5?